# mongoDB query return null, but with .toArray return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this query in mongoDB

```
var query = { "_id": new ObjectID(id)};
var items = {items:1};

warehouses.find(query, items,function (error, docs) {
    if (error) {
       error(error);
       return;
    }


    success(docs);
});
```

I want to get the items from a document by _id. This return me docs.items = undefined

But when i do:

```
warehouses.find(query, items).toArray(function (error, docs) {
            if (error) {
                error(error);
                return;
            }


            success(docs);
    });
```

Return me data:

```
0: Object
_id: ObjectID
items: Array[3]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
length: 3
```

How can i get the data with the first query? I want something like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a **big** difference. If you only expect **one** result, as in searching by the `_id` then use [**`.findOne()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findone):

```
warehouses.findOne(query, items, function (error, doc) {
```

Otherwise you are returning a [Cursor()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) object. At least so in the native driver and in some form or another in ODM's.